# From post-assessment to interview in a faculty recruitment in Denmark

Tags: faculty-application, interview, denmark

I have heard about cases in Denmark where candidates for a faculty position got through an assessment by some committee members as "qualified" but did not get interviews eventually. What is the process to go from post-assessment to interview in a faculty recruitment? For example, is there a ranking from the assessment committee? I am just curious since this procedure (post-assessment -> interview) seems obscure and hardly written in a university's hiring policies, even in a highly transparent system like in Scandinavian countries.

Comment: Can you explain more what your question is? Indeed, not all positively assessed candidates are invited, so there's a filtering. But that's already given from what you've heard. So what's left to clarify? Or do you just want a confirmation that what you've heard is correct?

Comment: Often there are formal qualifications you must have before you can even be considered for that job. These minimum qualifications can come from the law, or from university policy, or are specific to that position. So those who do not meet those criteria are first removed. The remaining candidates are than often ranked based on the material they provided, and the top X candidates are invited for an interview. You cannot invite everybody, otherwise we would be in selection committees all day and not get any teaching and research done.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper See my edits.  I would like to know about the usual procedure from post-assessment until interview, since universities' policy statement usually misses it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The University of Copenhagen documents that part of their [recruitment process](https://employment.ku.dk/faculty/recruitment-process/) as follows:

> 4. Assessment
>
> • The Assessment Committee makes a non-prioritised assessment of the academic qualifications of applicants with respect to research, teaching and outreach and other requirements listed in the advertisement.
>
> • HR undertakes legality checks and sends assessments out to applicants for consultation.
>
> 5. Interviews
>
> • The manager tasked with recruitment decides in conjunction with the Appointments Committee which of the applicants submitted for assessment are to be invited for interview and possibly a trial lecture.
>
> • Academic and personal characteristics are assessed and explored in more detail at interview.

So, there is a selection, but no ranking.